# I am currently working on Knapsack and using class but i having a trouble that the variables can not be access(Variables in knapsack class)

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

This is the full code

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Knapsack
class Knapsack {
public:
    Knapsack(int capacity, const vector<int>& weights, const vector<int>& values)
        : capacity_(capacity), weights_(weights), values_(values) {}
        
    const std::vector<int>& getWeights() const {
        return weights_;
    }

    const std::vector<int>& getValues() const {
        return values_;
    }

    int getCapacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }
private:
    int capacity_;
    vector<int> weights_;
    vector<int> values_;
}
```

I have tried to get variables but it not working the text editor gave me a warning that variables(weight, values and capacity) can not access

```cpp
    const std::vector<int>& getWeights() const {
        return weights_;
    }

    const std::vector<int>& getValues() const {
        return values_;
    }

    int getCapacity() const {
        return capacity_;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the exact text of the error message and the code that causes the error. I am not sure I see an error in the code that is presented.

Comment: 1) Text editor add-ins do not produce the most reliable diagnostics, you want to worry more about warnings from the compiler. 2) Is there a reason for the partial repeat of the code at the bottom of your post? That is a repeat and not additional contents, right? 3) Is this from a header (.h) file or a source (.cpp) file?

Comment: int calculateFitness(const vector<int>& chromosome) {
        int total_weight = 0;
        int total_value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < knapsack_.weights_.size(); i++) {
            if (chromosome[i] == 1) {
                total_weight += knapsack_.weights_[i];
                total_value += knapsack_.values_[i];
            }
        }
        if (total_weight > knapsack_.capacity_) {
            return 0;
        }
        return total_value;
    }
the error is in this function 
in the text editor its show me a warning told me that the variables is inaccessable

Comment: `knapsack_.capacity_` should be `knapsack_.getCapacity()`  you are not permitted to access `capacity_` `weights_` or  `values_` outside of the class. You have to use the getCapacity() getWeights and getValues() functions.

Comment: the partial code at the bottom is where i tried to get the variables in knapsack class

Comment: I'm still not clear on that, perhaps it doesn't matter. `calculateFitness()` should be included in your post. The errors there are genuine and can be dealt with exactly as @drescherjm's has already commented. That is what `private:` access does.

Comment: Check your code mark-up (next time). It was incorrect.  Fixed.  Add content that fixes or clarifies the question by editing the question, not by adding a comment.  SO is not a discussion forum, and as you can see, posting code in a comment does not really work.  This is C++ not C#, adding a getter does not create a property.  You have to explicitly call the getter.

Comment: Do not use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, it does not exist for all of the big 3 compilers. Get used to using namespaces correctly and avoid using `using namespace std;`, you will be better for it.